# str_replace characters with 2 other characters

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace `,` with `.` and `'` with `

I can do it like this

```
$bodyweight = str_replace("'", "`", $form->data['bodyweight']);
$bodyweight = str_replace(',', '.', $bodyweight);
```

Is the a way to do it in one str_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$bodyweight = str_replace(array("'", ','), array("`", '.'), $form->data['bodyweight']);
```